# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, exc-bad-instruction

I'm creating a temperature converter. When I run the application; enter a temperature, select which conversion and click convert. An error comes up.
THE ERROR IS: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

This is my code for ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var orginalValue: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var convertFrom: UIPickerView!
let pickerData = ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    convertFrom.dataSource = self
    convertFrom.delegate = self
}

@IBOutlet weak var labelConvertFrom: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var convertTo: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var labelConverTo: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var answer: UILabel!

@IBAction func convertButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let a = Double(orginalValue.text!)
    let tempConvertM = TempConvert(temp: a!)
    answer.text = String(tempConvertM.convert())

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    labelConvertFrom.text = pickerData[row]
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Here is where I'm getting the error.
TempConverterModel.swift

```
 import Foundation

 extension ViewController{
 class TempConvert{

    var temp:Double
    var view = ViewController()

    init (temp:Double){
        self.temp = temp
    }

    func convert()->Double{
        if(view.labelConvertFrom.text == "Celsius"){ -->ERROR IS HIGHLIGHTED HERE <--
           view.labelConverTo.text = "Fahrenheit"
           return (temp-32)/1.8000; //fahrenheit formula
        }
        else{
            view.labelConverTo.text = "Celsius"
            return (temp*1.8000)+32; //celsius formula
        }

    }
}
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I want to check the text in labelConvertFrom and check if it equals to "Celsius". IF it does not then return answer.

I would really appreciate anyones help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [par](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312594/par) pointed out, you should be removing the enclosing `extension ViewController { }` and have your `TempConvert` as a separate class.

Also, instead of trying to access the `ViewController`'s instance variables in `TempConvert`, you should be doing the comparisons in your `convertButton()` method in `ViewController` class itself and call the appropriate conversion method in `TempConvert` class.

A better approach is to have a stored property for "Celsius" and a computed property for "Fahrenheit" within your `ViewController` class. You can refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) for Properties in Swift language

Comment: This worked. I did as you said and did the comparisons in the convertButton.
THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: If this worked for you, you can mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem broadly stems from this line in `class TempConvert`:

`var view = ViewController()`

Here you are initializing an empty view controller.  The outlets you've defined such as `labelConvertFrom` are not hooked up to anything, so when you try to deference them here:

`view.labelConvertFrom.*text`

you crash (specifically, you crash where I put the `*` character). The reason you crash is because at that point, `labelConvertFrom` is `nil`.

To get this to work right, you'll need to initialize the ViewController using the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method, passing the correct nib filename and bundle id (which is probably just `NSBundle.mainBundle()`).

Doing this will allow your outlets to be hooked up properly and then they won't be `nil` when you try to use them.

Comment: My apologies. I'm new to Swift and this is my first app with iOS
I don't quite understand. How do I initialize the ViewController?
Would I do that in the ViewController class or TempCovert?

Comment: `let viewController = UIViewController(nibName: "mynibfile.xib", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())`  ... of course replace the nibName parameter with the actual name of your nib file.

Comment: You can do it in the `TempConvert`class.  And another side note, it doesn't matter entirely in terms of it working, but the `TempConvert` class shoudn't be an extension class of `UIViewController`.  Just put it in its own file `TempConvert.swift` and remove the enclosing `extension UIViewController {}`

Comment: Does this mean I have to create a nib file? I don't see any of my files with .xib

Comment: I really appreciate your help Par.

Comment: Yes, you will need a nib file or a storyboard.  Start with a new Swift project in Xcode and the ViewController will be already setup for you.  Move your code into it and it should start working.  Alternately you could set every field up programmatically (manually), but I don't recommend that if you're just starting out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95404/discussion-between-marcella-ruiz-and-par).